# canvas getImageData is black for images when source is in a document.implementation.createHTMLDocument object

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a source where html comes into my script that needs processing. The data contains image tags which have their source set to base64 encoded images. Lets say it's a textarea for this example:

```
<textarea id=src>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
</textarea>
```

If I create a virtual html document from this string value (eg. it's not attached to the real dom):

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("foo");
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = document.getElementById("src").value;
```

then make a canvas (created on the same `doc` object; but creating it on `document` causes the same problem) and copy the image element from the document onto a 2d rendering context in the canvas

```
var c = doc.createElement("canvas"), ctx = c.getContext('2d');
c.width = 20; c.height = 20; // for example
ctx.drawImage(doc.querySelector("img"), 0, 0);
```

then examine the image data from that context and find the colour values of each pixel

```
var d = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 20, 20);
for (var i=0;i<d.data.length;i+=4) {
        console.log(d.data[i],d.data[i+1],d.data[i+2]);
}
```

the pixels are all zero (e.g. black). I presume that there's some reason that canvas getimagedata isn't able to read the pixels if the source image isn't attached to a rendered dom object? I can't find any documentation on why this is the case or alternatives for getting the pixel data.

http://jsbin.com/tagacuxero/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `getImageData()`'s fault, but the [*update-the-image-data](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#update-the-image-data)* <img>'s internal method's one.

Indeed, this algorithm requires that the element's document be active.

> When the user agent is to update the image data of an img element, optionally with the restart animations flag set, it must run the following steps:
>
> - If the element's node document is not the [active document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#active-document), then:
>
>   - Continue running this algorithm in parallel.
>   - Wait until the element's node document is the [active document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#active-document).
>   - [...]

The document you did create with DocumentImplementation methods will never be active, and thus the `<img>` you created from there will never load.

In any way, you **must** wait for the onload event of your `<img>` before drawing it to the canvas. But in this case, this event won't fire, so you might want to load it from an `<img>` element that belongs to your main Document, or to *adopt* at least this <img> element from your active Document.

```js
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
var img = doc.createElement('img');
img.onload = e => console.log('I did load.',
  'I belong to ', 
    (img.ownerDocument === doc && 'doc') ||
    (img.ownerDocument === window.document && 'window.document') ||
    'nobody...'
);
img.onerror = e=> console.log('Will not even fire...');
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png';

onclick = e => {
  console.log('adopting the <img> node');
  document.adoptNode(img);
};
```

```html
click anywhere to make the active Document adopts the &lt;img>.
```